# Find an executable using Qt5

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

I am developing an application based on Qt5, and I need to see whether a particular application is installed. The current method I am using is

```
QFile::exists("/usr/bin/program")
```

But this amounts to hard-coding the executable path. Is there a better method of doing this via Qt5's built in functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [QStandardPaths::findExecutable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#findExecutable). But be aware that this is only to be taken informative, by the time you really want to execute it, it could have been uninstalled, so always handle errors anyways.